# How do I restore learned spelling from a backup?

Tags: macos

I have an old backup of my user Library and need to restore its previous learned spelling values. Where do I find it within that old backup library?

Answer (score 1):

The user dictionary should be located in ~/Library/Spelling (/Users/You/Library/Spelling). Are you unable to restore that folder from your backup?

Comment: What as puzzling me was at the root of my User Library there was no "Spelling" folder. Asked an Apple Advisor what to do. Told me to copy the whole "Spelling" folder from backup. Then rebuild permissions as instructed in the "Resolution" part of http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4040. He added one more fine tuning. After you've performed step 4 but before step 5, with the padlock open, change the admin user from Read & Write to Read Only. Then change it back to Read & Write permission. This will force the system to note something has changed, thus ensuring the procedure proceeds. It worked for me.